# Quiero que la imagen insertada en el canvas no atraviese los bordes sino que estos sean sus limites

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, function

```js
var x= 220, y= 730;

        function lienzo(){

            var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            var img = document.getElementById("ima");
            ctx.clearRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
            ctx.drawImage(ima,x,y);
        }

           

        function whichButton(event){
            if(event.keyCode=='39'){
                x = x + 5;
                lienzo();
            }

            if(event.keyCode=='37'){
                x = x - 5;
                lienzo();
            }

            if(event.keyCode=='38'){
                y = y - 5;
                lienzo();
            }

            if(event.keyCode=='40'){
                y = y + 5;
                lienzo();
            }


        }

        function limitesPared(){
          
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Game</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <marquee scrollamonunt="900" direction="left">Juego producido por Figueroa Company</marquee> 

 </head>

  
 
 <body onkeydown="whichButton(event)" onload="lienzo()"onload="game.init()">

  <div align="center">
   <canvas id="myCanvas" width="500%" height="800%" style="border:3px solid green;background-color:#000000;">
   <img id="ima" src="bueno.png">
  </div>


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. La imagen sale del `canvas` porque la pintas a partir de  x= 220, y= 730. Para que esto no pase pintalo a partir de x=0,y=0: `ctx.drawImage(ima, 0, 0)`;
2. Si quieres que los bordes del `canvas` sean los limites de la imagen tienes que hacer el canvas tan grande que la imagen. Así que en lugar de dar al `canvas` una anchura y una altura en el HTML, hazlo en el javascript.

Me gustaría saber que significan las variables `var x = 220,y = 730;`. ¿Acaso representan el tamaño de tu imagen?

```js
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;
```

```js
var img = document.getElementById("ima");
//var x = 220,
//y = 730;

function lienzo() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  c.width = img.width;
  c.height = img.height;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.drawImage(ima, 0, 0);
}

lienzo();
```

```html
<body onkeydown="whichButton(event)" onload="lienzo()"onload="game.init()">

    <div align="center">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" style="border:3px solid green;background-color:#000000;">
        <img id="ima" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/beagle400.jpg" >
          </canvas>
    </div>


</body>
```

#### actualización

El OP comenta:

> Las variables X=220, Y=730; son para que cuando actualice la pagina la imagen aparezca en esas posiciones (centro del canvas parte inferior)

Lo que entiendo es que el canvas tiene una anchura de 220*2 y una altura de 730, y que la imagen tiene que aparecer en el centro del canvas a la parte inferior. En este caso el código sería esto:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("ima");

function lienzo() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  c.width = 440;
  c.height = 730;
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.drawImage(ima, (c.width-img.width)/2, c.height-img.height);
}

lienzo();
```

```css
canvas{background:black;}
```

```html
<div align="center">
  <canvas id="myCanvas">
  <img id="ima" src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/pin.png">
</canvas>
</div>
```

Para dibujar una imagen podemos utilizar `contexto.drawImage(img,x,y);` donde x e y representan las coordenadas de le esquina superior arriba de la imagen. En este caso la anchura y la altura de la imagen pintada en el canvas son iguales a la altura y la anchura de la imagen utilizada. Así que para pintar la imagen en el **centro del canvas parte inferior** hay que escribir `ctx.drawImage(ima, (c.width-img.width)/2, c.height-img.height);`

Comment: Las variables X=220, Y=730; son para que cuando actualice la pagina la imagen aparezca en esas posiciones (centro del canvas parte inferior) porque hago un juego y la imagen (player) la muevo con las flechas del teclado pero atraviensan los bordes del canvas y quiero que todo se desarrolle dentro de el